# Using the Facebook Android sdk, is it possible to retrieve a listing of Events?

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-events

I took a look at the api and it appears that I can only pull the events associated with a user. What I would like to do is pull events that may or may not be associated with a user. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for Events via the `/search?type=event&q={your_query}` endpoint. Have a look at the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#searchtypes